# How to remove element from XML in Camel route?

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-camel

Suppose I have next XML coming from Oracle queue to Camel route:

```
<book>
    <author>Jack London</author>
    <name>White Fang</name>
    <publisher>Penguin</publisher>
    <year>1905</year>
    <price>25USD</price>
</book>
```

I want to process this exchange body in my route and remove some element, e.g. `price` and proceed with body:

```
<book>
    <author>Jack London</author>
    <name>White Fang</name>
    <publisher>Penguin</publisher>
    <year>1935</year>
</book>
```

What is the easiest way for doing this? Of course it can be done by declaring some bean or Camel processor that takes body as XML marshal/unmarshal it and return back.

But I wonder if there is another way out of the box in Camel?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this without bean or processor in the next way in the Camel route using `transform()` and regex replacement:

```
from(source)
  .log(DEBUG, log, "Initial message: ${body}")
  .transform(body().regexReplaceAll("<price>\\.*<\\/price>",""))
  .log(DEBUG, log, "Processed message: ${body}")
  .to(destination);
```